Huffy Sea Pines from the late 70's.The hub will slip
What should I do when I hit bumps or put on the pedals and it will switch gears momentarily.
It is an Internally Geared Hub.
The bicycle looks similar to this (via Reddit)


Can you add a clear and well-lit photo of your bike's transmission area please?  That should show the condition of teeth.  Also, check your chain for wear with a chain-checker tool, or by either precisely measuring 12 links in length, or by checking for pull-away at the forewardmost tip of the chain ring, or by feeling for play in any untensioned link.   Use [edit] to add this info.

It is a internal hub.

okay that eliminates a derailleur but now adds the question of chain tension overall.

Knowing how to adjust the shifting on an internally geared hub is dependent on the manufacturer. There is usually something stamped on the hub somewhere to provide a clue. This information is critical to a good answer.

If indeed it is a Sturmey Archer internal hub (most likely 3speed, can also be 5sp), the cause of your issues can be :

Chain slip, to low tension where your chain is not grabbing the sprocket properly.  but believe me, you'd notice that
improper adjustment of internal hub.  This causes the engaging teeth not to be properly aligned. check Sheldon Browns SA 3sp adjustment page here : https://www.sheldonbrown.com/sturmey-archer/adj.html
You internals need lube or are busted : most likely the little pawls (springs) worn out, or worse broken.
You need to avoid riding the bike if you feel it 'slip' of a gear into another, as that might cause a lot more damage internally. If it just stuck at 1 gear (or disconnect the chainlink) it's ok to ride it.  not ideal but it would get you home :)


<this is going to be rough and tough, probably reported and taken down>
Learn to ride:

ass off the saddle just before any bumps
oil Your chain monthly at the very least
first point didn't help? hands loose on the bars!
even a rear brake must be able to bring You to a complete stop within 5 meters
beautiful bycicle!


What makes you think it's the rider's technique rather than a mechanical issue? What if they're already doing all these things and they're still having a problem?
